# Euler Mascheroni Constant

Tags: real-analysis

I know that $$\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty }\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\ln(n)\right).$$
I'm trying to prove that we also have 
$$\gamma=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k}-\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\right).$$

So,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{k}-\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^n(\ln(k+1)-\ln(k)).$$
But $$\sum_{k=1}^n(\ln(k+1)-\ln(k))=\ln(n+1)$$ and thus, I get

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty  \left(\frac{1}{k}-\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty }\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\ln(n+1)\right),$$

hat's wrong here ?

Comment: The limits are the same - try subtracting one from the other.

Comment: Let $H_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k}$. On the one hand, you know $\gamma = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} H_n - \ln n$, on the other you get $\gamma = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} H_n - \ln (n+1)$. But $\ln (n+1) - \ln n = \ln (1+1/n) \to 0$.

Comment: Nothing's wrong, you just achieved the proof.

Comment: $\ln(n+1)=\ln n + O(1/n)$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
We have: 
$$\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{i})-ln(n)$$
And:
$$\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\dfrac{1}{i}-ln(1+\dfrac{1}{i}))$$
Which is the same as:
$$\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\dfrac{1}{i})-\sum_{i=1}^{n}ln(1+\dfrac{1}{i})$$
We can subtract them from each other and get:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}ln(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}ln(1+\dfrac{1}{i})$$
Since $ln(a)+ln(b)=ln(ab)$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}ln(n)=ln(\prod_{i=1}^{n}1+\dfrac{1}{i})$$
And thus:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n=\prod_{i=1}^{n}1+\dfrac{1}{i}$$

Comment: I don't find this way of describing the solution good - you are starting by assuming what we have to prove, and you end up arriving at something that's clearly true.

Comment: Well, if it;s true then we can reason 'back' to the original equations, so...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem just amounts to evaluating an easy telescoping product,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac1k\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(\frac{k+1}k\right)=\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{1}\right).$$