# Let $\gamma_n=-\ln n+\sum_{k=1}^{n}1/k$ and let $\gamma$ be the Euler-Mascheroni constant

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\gamma_n=-\ln n+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac1k$ and let $\gamma$ be the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\gamma_{n}$. Evaluate $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\gamma_{n}-\gamma-\frac{1}{2n}\right)\cdot$$

Please give a hint to proceed the problem. I have tried to proceed but could not go further.

Comment: [Avoid no-clue questions.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933/721644) MSE isn't a _service_ site. You haven't shown any effort or work in [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3670194/721644) either.

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1430697/721644)

Comment: It's a shame you closed this, because the solution is very nice, in my opinion. Many no clue questions never get closed, and as far as they go, this is one of the more interesting ones.

Comment: Yǒngyuǎn kuàilè.......

Answer (score 4):

We have the following result.

**Proposition**.
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\gamma_{n}-\gamma-\frac{1}{2n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(H_n-\log n-\gamma-\frac1{2n}\right)=\frac{1+\gamma-\log 2\pi}2,
$$
with the harmonic number $\displaystyle H_{n}=1+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1n$.

One may take an integral point of view.

A hint.

**Step 1**. Converting the summand to an integral,
$$H_n-\log n-\gamma-\frac1{2n}=-\int_0^1\!\left(\!\frac1{\log x}+\frac1{1-x}-\frac12\!\right)\!x^{n-1}\:dx,\quad n\ge1.
$$
**Step 2**. Converting the series to an integral,
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\gamma_{n}-\gamma-\frac{1}{2n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(H_n-\log n-\gamma-\frac1{2n}\right)=-\int_0^1\!\left(\!\frac1{\log x}+\frac1{1-x}-\frac12\!\right)\frac{1}{1-x}\:dx.
$$
**Step 3**. One may recall [Binet's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsLogGammaFormulas.html)
$$
\log \Gamma(z)= \! \left( z-\frac{1}{2}\right)\log z - z + \frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi) - \!\!
\int_0^{1} \!
\left(\frac{1}{\log x}+\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{x^{z-1}}{\log x}\mathrm{d}x, \quad {\mathrm{Re}} z >0,
$$ giving the desired result at $z=1$, having observed that
\begin{multline} 
\displaystyle \left(\frac1{\log x} + \frac1{1-x} - \frac{1}{2} \right) \frac1{1-x} = \left[x \left(\frac{1}{\log x} + \frac1{1-x}\right)\right]' \, \\
+ \left(\displaystyle \frac1{\log x} + \frac1{1-x} - \frac12 \right) \frac1{\log x} - \frac12 \left(\frac{1}{\log x} + \frac{1}{1-x}\right)
\end{multline}
and using
$$
\gamma = \int_0^1\left(\frac1{\log x} + \frac1{1-x}\right)dx.
$$

Comment: Awesome!! Great solution.

Comment: how we have got the integral in step 1?

Comment: @kokuio98 One may notice that $$\int_{0}^{1}\left({1\over \log{x}}+{1\over 1-x}\right)x^{n-1} dx=\int_{0}^{1}\left({1\over \log{x}}+{1\over 1-x}\right)dx+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{n-1}-1}{\log x} dx-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^{n-1}}{1-x}dx$$ and

Comment: ... and $$\int_{0}^{1}\left({1\over \log{x}}+{1\over 1-x}\right)dx=\gamma$$ $$ \int_{0}^{1}{\frac{{{x}^{n-1}}-1}{\ln x}}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}{\int_{0}^{n-1}{{{x}^{t}}}\,dt}\,dx=\int_{0}^{n-1}{\int_{0}^{1}{{{x}^{t}}}\,dx}\,dt=\int_{0}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{t+1}}dt=\log n$$ $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x}dx=H_{n}.$$

Answer (score 2):

For the harmonic numbers $H_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}1/k$, we have $$H_n=\ln n+\gamma+\frac1{2n}+O(n^{-2}),$$ and $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}H_k=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{l=1}^{k}\frac1l=\sum_{l=1}^{n}\sum_{k=l}^{n}\frac1l=(n+1)\,H_n-n.$$
Using Stirling's formula $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln k=\left(n+\frac12\right)\,\ln n-n+\frac12\,\ln(2\pi)+O(n^{-1}),$$ we arrive at $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(H_k-\ln k-\gamma-\frac1{2k}\right)=\frac12\,\left(1+\gamma-\ln(2\pi)\right)+O(n^{-1}).$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the digamma function $\displaystyle\psi(n+1)=-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^{n}1/k.$ Notice $\psi$ satisfies the functional equation $\psi(n+1)=\psi(n)+\frac{1}{n}.$

In terms of digamma, $$\gamma_n-\gamma-\frac{1}{2n}=-\ln(n)+\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k-\gamma-\frac{1}{2n}=\psi(n+1)-\ln(n)-\frac{1}{2n}.$$

There are some facts involving this quantity [(see)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Asymptotic_expansion), which require some work to prove. In particular *this quantity is always negative, so the sum should be negative.*

The important approximation from above is the following (using the approximation and the functional equation above):

$$\psi(n+1)-\ln(n)-\frac{1}{2n}=\psi(n)- \ln(n) + \frac{1}{2n} \approx -\frac{1}{12n^2},$$
so it seems the series does converge.

From here I'm completely stuck because the identities involving $\gamma_n-\gamma-\frac{1}{2n}$ using the digamma function are well-known, but can't be written in any nice way I can find. Notice that the partial sum of your series up to $n=10000$ (using Wolfram) gives an approximation of $-.1303,$ while $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty -\frac{1}{12n^2}=-\frac{\pi^2}{72}=-.13707...,$$
which is not too far off. I'd be extremely surprised if this sum had a nice closed form solution.

Edit: Well, I'm very surprised indeed the answer is $(1+\gamma -\ln(2\pi))/2\approx -0.1303$ from another answer!!